# creating a static library and linking using Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a application which need to use two libraries (pugixml and lua) and need to be an multi-platform build capable. I am trying to use Cmake for this. Since I have three different solution (two for creating static libraries and one solution which actually uses that libraries). So far what I do is run Cmake for those two libraries and copy those static libraries manually to the lib folder into application and run cmake again.

I need to reduce the three step and make it as a single step so that I can handle the multi-platform build in a single shot.

I need to know, should we need to create a dynamic link library or shared library or static library for these kind of operation?

And need help on how to do it. I tried creating the source folder of pugixml and copy the cpp/hpp/h file and wrote a cmakelists file like

```
set(HEADERS pugixml.hpp pugiconfig.hpp)
set(SOURCES ${HEADERS} pugixml.cpp)
add_library(pugixmlLib STATIC ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(pugixmlLib pugixml)
```

On the solution I could see my application project and pugixml project, but on my application project linker property I could find pugixml library.

Comment: Dynamic and shared are the same. The type doesn't really matter, but since you're building your custom versions for single purpose, I'd probably just go for static -- just one file to deal with. You should show all the relevant `CMakeLists.txt` files.

Comment: You could also create a project with three subprojects (pugixml, lua, your lib) and process them one after another with add_subdirectory. I agree with Dan that you should more information.